# Remove blue underline from link

Tags: css, hyperlink, underline

I am attempting to have a link show up in white, without an underline. The text color shows up correctly as white, but the blue underline is stubbornly persisting. I tried `text-decoration: none;` and `text-decoration: none !important;` in the CSS to remove the link underline. Neither worked.

```css
.boxhead .otherPage {
  color: #FFFFFF;
  text-decoration: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="boxhead">
  <h2>
    <span class="thisPage">Current Page</span>
    <a href="myLink"><span class="otherPage">Different Page</span></a>
  </h2>
</div>
```

How can I remove the blue underline from the link?

Comment: Well it should go away when you do text-decoration:none. Are you sure you are appling this to the right element? Can you provide example code?

Comment: Where is text-decoration: none being used?

Answer (score 984, accepted):

You are not applying `text-decoration: none;` to an anchor (`.boxhead a`) but to a span element (`.boxhead`).

Try this:

```
.boxhead a {
    color: #FFFFFF;
    text-decoration: none;
}
```

Comment: But what if you have text *surrounding* the span as well, and you want the surrounding text to have the link underline, but the text within the span to have none?

Comment: @JMTyler you can't have partial underlines like that, but I guess you could apply border on text inside of span.

Comment: Would it make a difference if it is a div?  And how exactly would applying a border cause the underline to appear gone?

Comment: @rebus, You can't?  Why not?  Cause in at least IE7+ and FireFox 4+ you can, but not in Chrome for some reason.  

Here's the code I got to work in the non-Chrome browsers I tested:
`.toc-list a > span{text-decoration:none !important;}`

I think @JMTyler's question is legitimate; I am searching for the same solution.

Comment: Twitter did the same with the message page you can see that the name has underline but not the tag

Comment: It appears `text-decoration` doesn't support overriding on nested tags, as hinted above. Once you have an `a { text-decoration: underline; }` rule applied you *cannot* de-apply it eg with `a .wish_this_were_not_underlined { text-decoration: none; }`. I can't find a reference for this but that's my experience (in Chrome).

Comment: Like others above I was not able to de-underline the text by applying `text-decoration: none;` so instead we chose to hide the line using `text-decoration: underline; text-decoration-color: white;`. /hack

Comment: Better yet, try `.hidden-underline { text-decoration-color: #00000000; }` to set the underline color to transparent (0 alpha). Mind, it is not widely supported as of today (Edge, looking at you).

Comment: if you're only trying to remove the underline from an element inside an anchor, and not the entire anchor. you need to make the inner element an inline-block like so:

`.boxhead .otherPage {
  display: inline-block;
  color: #FFFFFF;
  text-decoration: none;
}`

Answer (score 270):

The anchor tag (link) also has pseudo-classes such as visited, hover, link and active. Make sure your style is applied to the state(s) in question and that no other styles are conflicting.

For example:

```
a:hover, a:visited, a:link, a:active
{
    text-decoration: none;
}
```

See [W3.org](https://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/#useraction-pseudos) for more information on **user action pseudo-classes :hover, :active, and :focus.**

Comment: I think you mean `a:link` when you say `a:click`

Comment: This should be the actual accepted answer, as I was having the same problem AFTER clicking on my button link. The visited property was still changing to purple when I came back to the page.

Answer (score 36):

`text-decoration: none !important` should remove it .. Are you sure there isn't a `border-bottom: 1px solid` lurking about? (Trace the computed style in Firebug/F12 in IE)

Comment: Setting `border-bottom-style: none;` fixed it for me.

Answer (score 32):

Just add this attribute to your anchor tag

`style="text-decoration:none;"`

Example:

```
<a href="page.html"  style="text-decoration:none;"></a>
```

Or use the CSS way.

```
.classname a {
    color: #FFFFFF;
    text-decoration: none;
}
```

Answer (score 21):

Sometimes you're seeing a box shadow, not a text underline.

Try this (using whatever CSS selectors are appropriate for you):

```
a:hover, a:visited, a:link, a:active {
  text-decoration: none !important;
  -webkit-box-shadow: none !important;
  box-shadow: none !important;
}
```

Comment: This one should be the answer.. Sometimes, box shadow gives an underline affect.

Comment: It is an answer, but not the best. The scope of those are global and not specific. Something like this should do the trick: `.otherPage a:link {text-decoration:none;}`; repeat that for visited, active and hover if needed.

Answer (score 17):

You missed  `text-decoration:none` for the **anchor tag**. So the code should be the following.

```css
.boxhead a {
    text-decoration: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="boxhead">
    <h2>
        <span class="thisPage">Current Page</span>
        <a href="myLink"><span class="otherPage">Different Page</span></a>
    </h2>
</div>
```

More standard properties for text-decoration

[image]

Answer (score 11):

As a rule, if your "underline" is not the same color as your text (and the 'color:' is not overridden inline), it is not coming from "text-decoration:". It has to be "border-bottom:".

Don't forget to take the border off your pseudo classes too!

```
a, a:link, a:visited, a:active, a:hover {border:0!important;}
```

This snippet assumes it's on an anchor. Change to its wrapper accordingly... And use specificity instead of "!important" after you track down the root cause.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/text-decoration-color

Answer (score 9):

Without seeing the page, it is hard to speculate.

But it sounds to me like you may have a `border-bottom: 1px solid blue;` being applied. Perhaps add `border: none;`. `text-decoration: none !important` is right; it's possible that you have another style that is still overriding that CSS though.

This is where using the [Firefox Web Developer Toolbar](https://addons.mozilla.org/addon/60) is awesome. You can edit the CSS right there and see if things work, at least for Firefox. It's under *CSS* → *Edit CSS*.

Answer (score 5):

```
  a {
    color: unset;
    text-decoration: unset;
  }
```

Answer (score 4):

While the other answers are correct, there is an easy way to get rid of the underline on all those pesky links:

```
a {
   text-decoration: none;
}
```

This will remove the underline from *every single link* on your page!

Comment: make sure its on the anchor tag and inline could be better since you might want the underline on other links.

Answer (score 3):

None of the answers worked for me. In my case there was a standard

```css
a:-webkit-any-link {
    text-decoration: underline;
```

in my code. Basically whatever link it is, the text color goes blue, and the link stays whatever it is.

So I added the code at the end of the header like this:

```html
<head>
  </style>
    a:-webkit-any-link {
      text-decoration: none;
    }
  </style>
</head>
```

And the problem is no more.

Comment: [Example 1](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:any-link) (MDN) and [example 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35303995/cannot-override-webkit-any-link) (Stack Overflow) of using "`a:-webkit-any-link {`".

Answer (score 3):

### Update 2023

The question is already a bit older. Since a while you can delete all features of a tag with `all: unset` in CSS.

```css
.w {
  font-size: 1.4rem;
}

.w .s2 a, .w .s3 a {
  all: unset;
}

.w .s3 a {
  color: magenta;
}
```

```html
<div class="w">
  <div class="s1">
    <a href="">link A</a>
  </div>
  
  <div class="s2">
    <a href="">link B</a>
  </div>  
  
  <div class="s3">
    <a href="">link C</a>
  </div>    
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

You've used *text-decoration: none* in the wrong selector. You need to check which tag do you need for decoration *none*.

You may use this code

```
.boxhead h2 a {
    text-decoration: none;
}
```

*Or*

```
.boxhead a {
    text-decoration: none !important;
}
```

*Or*

```
a {
    text-decoration: none !important;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

As others pointed out, it seems like you can't override nested text-decoration styles... *But* you can change the *text-decoration-color*.

As a hack, I changed the color to be transparent:

```
    text-decoration-color: transparent;
```

Answer (score 2):

In my reset, the CSS usually is:

```css
a {
  cursor: pointer;
  text-decoration: none !important;
  color: inherit;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Just use the property

```
border: 0;
```

and you are covered. It worked perfectly for me when the *text-decoration* property didn’t work at all.

Answer (score 1):

If `text-decoration: none` or `border: 0` doesn't work, try applying inline style in your HTML content.

Comment: How exactly? Can you elaborate? E.g., by providing an example?

Answer (score 0):

Put the following HTML code before the 
`<BODY>` tag:

`<STYLE>A {text-decoration: none;} </STYLE>`

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I had poorly formed HTML. The link was within a `<u>` tag, and not a `<ul>` tag.

Answer (score 0):

Set `text-decoration: none;` for the anchor tag.

Example HTML.

```
<body>
    <ul class="nav-tabs">
        <li><a href="#"><i class="fas fa-th"></i>Business</a></li>
        <li><a href="#"><i class="fas fa-th"></i>Expertise</a></li>
        <li><a href="#"><i class="fas fa-th"></i>Quality</a></li>
    </ul>
</body>
```

Example CSS:

```
.nav-tabs li a{
  text-decoration: none;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Overriding *nested* text-decoration styles.

Look for any **::before or ::after** selectors and display none to any text-decoration, border-bottom, etc. or reset a property (unset) to any text color property like: *text-decoration-color*, *background-color*, etc.

```
.boxhead .otherPage {
    color: #FFFFFF;
}

a.boxhead .otherPage:before {
    background-color: unset;
}
```

or

```
a.boxhead .otherPage:before {
    background-color: unset !important;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Here is an example for the [ASP.NET](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASP.NET) [Web Forms](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-forms/what-is-web-forms) LinkButton control:

```
 <asp:LinkButton ID="lbmmr1" runat="server" ForeColor="Blue" />
```

[Code-behind](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/code-behind#Noun):

```
 lbmmr1.Attributes.Add("style", "text-decoration: none;")
```