# I can not get rid of a underline text

Tags: css, underline, text-decorations

I got this code:

```
<div class="class1"><a href="http://nvm/">text</a></div>
```

CSS code of class1 is following:

```
.class1 {
       text-decoration: none;
}
```

The output looks on, until I move the mouse over the `div`. The text is underlined then.

Sure, I've tried a lot of methods like:

```
.class1:hover {
      text-decoration: none;
}
```

I've also tried to add a `!important` attribute, but still without expected results. :/

I've also used firebug to debug the HTML & CSS code, and I can't find any class with attribute `text-decoration: underline;`.

I know this is such a silly question, but I'm out of ideas.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Remove stubborn underline from link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2789703/remove-stubborn-underline-from-link)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should set the `text-decoration` property to `none` for the `a` element inside of `.class1`, since that is the element that contains the text (and likely the element that you are hovering on).

For example:

`.class1 a` (all `a` tags whose ancestor is `.class1`)

OR

`.class1 > a` (all `a` tags whose parent is `.class1`)

Comment: Thanks you. 
`.pagination > a {
 text-decoration: none !important;
}`

worked... finally :)

Answer (score 1):

If you're setting a global `<a>` property elsewhere, you'll need to specifically override the `<a>` tags for that class.

`.class1 a { text-decoration: none; }`

and

`.class1 a:hover {text-decoration: none; }`

depending on if you have a global hover defined too

Answer (score 0):

```
div.class1 a { Properties:values}
```

Would be a good practice.