# Removing an underline from a link in css

Tags: html, css

I've been trying to remove an ugly underline from a webpage but for some reason it just won't go away.

I've tried using `text-decoration:none;` and `color: #FFFFFF;` to no avail.

Original css:

```
#noday {
    color: #ECECEC;
    font-family: "Times New Roman",Times,serif;
    font-size: 1em;
}
```

The snippet of code:

```
<a href="http://www.example.com/content/" target"_blank"><div id="noday"><br><br>Random text here</div></a>
```

### Real example: http://jsfiddle.net/c0c6g4rd/

I've looked at: [Remove stubborn underline from link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2789703/remove-stubborn-underline-from-link) but it hasn't helped :/

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Just add `text-decoration:none;` to `a` tag for `#noneall`:

```
#noneall a{
    text-decoration:none;
}
```

Here is a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/c0c6g4rd/3/).

Comment: Or more generally `a { text-decoration: none; }`

Answer (score 2):

Try this, add a `id`(or `class`) to your `a href`

```
<a href="http://www.example.com/content/" id="thisLink" target"_blank">Random text here</a>
```

and add this to your css file:

```
#thisLink{
    text-decoration: none;
}
```

This should remove the underline!

Here a Jsfiddle of that:

http://jsfiddle.net/c0c6g4rd/4/

Answer (score 2):

Add at the beginning of your css file:

```
a{
 text-decoration:none;
}
```

With these lines you will remove this underline from **all** links in your html.

Answer (score 0):

Just to make sure, try adding a `!important` after your `text-decoration: none`:

```
a{text-decoration: none !important}
```

If that does work, then there is a hierarchy problem and something else is overriding your declaration.  Also try putting your declaration at the END of your CSS to override any other declarations.

Answer (score 0):

The root of this problem is that you can't put a `div` (a block-level element) inside an `a` (an inline element. However, there are better ways of doing what you're trying to do.

As the others said, this will apply to all links:

```
a { text-decoration: none; }
```

However, if you only want to apply it to that one link, add the id to the `a` like this rather than using another element:

```
<a ... id="noday">...</a>
```

Then style the same way.

Fiddles of examples:

http://jsfiddle.net/9gsu9ok3/ (Style all links)

http://jsfiddle.net/9gsu9ok3/3/ (Style only certain links)

Hope this helps.