# Can I remove all Underline from the links at once?

Tags: html, css

I need to remove all underlines from the all links at once, is this possible?

[image: Underline issue]

[Here is the template](https://drive.google.com/file/d/17qdZA2gv_Rmg0xwEPTsTGpEZbe3FpCCs/view?usp=sharing)

Comment: Duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26456617/removing-an-underline-from-a-link-in-css

Answer (score 1):

This should do it for you...

`<style> a { text-decoration: none; } </style>`

Answer (score 0):

add this to your csss

```
*{
  text-decoration: none;
 }
```

Answer (score -1):

```
text-decoration:none; a tag in css
```

```css
text-decoration:none;
```

Answer (score -1):

I suggest my solution because in this case it only deletes links within the table.

```
  tr td ul li a {
            text-decoration: none;
        }
```