# How do I make a div clickable in html and css without underlining?

Tags: html, hyperlink, clickable

Goodday,

I'm currently working on a page where I want to have a div clickable.

Got this far:

```
<a href="http://coteax.me/">
 <div id ="rectangle">
   <div id="iconx"></div>
 <p class="rec-text"> Portal for projects</p>
 </div>
</a>
```

It works but the text is underlined with a purple line (Hypertext ?)
How do I make it so that the purple line is gone and the text just clickable ?

Many thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

You can just remove the underline by CSS, Check the CSS part of the example.

Example from [Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2789703/remove-stubborn-underline-from-link):

The HTML:

```
<div class="boxhead">
    <h2>
        <span class="thisPage">Current Page</span>
        <a href="myLink"><span class="otherPage">Different Page</span></a>
    </h2>
</div>
```

The CSS:

```
.boxhead .otherPage {
    color: #FFFFFF;
    text-decoration: none;
}
```

Comment: Thanks! I'll take a look at it!

Answer (score 0):

HTML

```
<div id="iconx">
...
</div>
```

CSS

```
#iconx {
 cursor : pointer;
}
```

JQUERY

```
$('body').find("#iconx").delegate("click", function() {
 location.href="http://coteax.me/"
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Just Use `text-decoration: none`.

```html
<a href="http://coteax.me/" style="text-decoration: none;"><div id ="rectangle"><div id="iconx"></div><p class="rec-text"> Portal for projects</p></div></a>
```

**OR (Using External CSS)**

```css
a {
    text-decoration: none;
}
```

```html
<a href="http://coteax.me/">
    <div id ="rectangle">
        <div id="iconx"></div>
        <p class="rec-text">Portal for projects</p>
    </div>
</a>
```