# How do i make my menu buttons not look like links?

Tags: html, css

I have 3 buttons on my page and i was wondering if there is a way for them to not be underlined and dark blue like a link would be. so how do i make it not underlined?[see what i mean here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xBEG6.png)

```
 <div class="menu">
        <ul>
            <li class="logo"> <a href="TributePage.html"> <img src="images/logo.png"></a></li>
            <li><a href="TributePage.html">Home</a></li>
            <li><a href="about.html">About</a></li>
            <li><a href="albums.html">Albums</a></li>
            
         </ul>
     </div>
```

```
.menu ul{ 
display: inline-flex; 
margin: 50px; 
font-family: 'Staatliches', cursive; 
font-size: 25px; 
} 
.menu ul li{ 
list-style: none; 
margin: 0 20px; 
color: #1385d6;
cursor: pointer; }
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Remove stubborn underline from link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2789703/remove-stubborn-underline-from-link)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

CSS

```
.menu ul li a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: (whatever you want that isn't purple/blue)
}
```

Comment: ty bro i know this was probs very simple but im new to html and css this helps alot

Comment: No problem. We all had to start somewhere! Please mark my answer as accepted if it helped you.

Answer (score 0):

You need to remove default css from `a` tag:

```
.menu ul li a, .menu ul li a:hover, .menu ul li a:focus{
  text-decoration: none;
  color: pink; 
}
```