# Style a React Router Link

Tags: react-router

**Problem:** I'm using React Router Links and I can't figure out how to style them (I want to change font color and delete the underline).

I've been reading different documents but still can't figure out how to do this. One page said to just use NavLink instead of Link. I've used NavLink to create a navigation bar on my page and I've styled that with no problems but I feel like using a NavLink when it's not up in the navigation bar probably isn't the correct way to go?

[Print screen of code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1q47M.png)
[Print screen of page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yrq3b.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create a className called "default-link"
and then do text-decoration none;

```
.default-link{
  text-decoration: none !important;
}
```

feel free to let me know if this is what you meant.
An example of it can be found here: [Remove stubborn underline from link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2789703/remove-stubborn-underline-from-link)

Comment: omg yes, thank you this works! I feel so silly, wonder how I have not solved this on my own when it's basically exactly what I've done with my NavLinks. I really made this more complicated than it was... ;)